# Java array values as hashset

Tags: java, arrays, hashset

I am new to Java and I literally have no idea how to do this.

I have this Java array:

```
String luni[];
luni = new String[] {"A","B","C"};
```

and I want each value `A`,`B`,`C` from the array to become a `HashSet` variable, like this:

```
Set<String> luni[0] = new HashSet<>(500);
Set<String> luni[1] = new HashSet<>(500);
Set<String> luni[2] = new HashSet<>(500);
```

Eventually having `A`,`B`,`C` as `HashSet` to which I can later use `luni[0].add("string");`
I hope you get the idea. How can I do this, it seems it won't work as I wrote it?

Comment: the variable name can't be **dynamic** in JAVA. Not possible in Java

Comment: so, is there a workaround ?

Comment: Better use `Map<String,Set<String>>` to contains the key-value pairs where `A`, `B` and `C` are keys

Comment: Why do you need the "A", "B","C" there? You can have an array of HashSets if you like.

Comment: @RealSkeptic how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original answer was:

> If you just need to access each HashSet in the array by index,
>   `luni[0].add("string")`, then you simply have to define `luni` as an
>   array of Sets:

But in fact, you'll need to use an ArrayList of Sets (or use an array of raw Set, but that's not as good), and you'll still be able to use it with an index:

Note that this is only good if you don't have any actual use for the "A", "B", "C" and you just wanted to access the hashsets by index.

```
    List<Set<String>> luni = new ArrayList<Set<String>>();

    luni.add(  new HashSet<String>(500) );
    luni.add(  new HashSet<String>(500) );
    luni.add(  new HashSet<String>(500) );

    luni.get(0).add("String");
```

Comment: this won't compile, `Set<String>[] luni = new Set<String>[3];` has errors saying "generic array creation".

Comment: OK, I revised the answer. Use an ArrayList instead of an array. Youcan still get the elements by index.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `HashMap` in your case  it will have a `String` keys and `HashSet` values.

```
HashMap<String, HashSet<Whatever>> map 
    = new HashMap<String, HashSet<Whatever>>();
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use:

```
Map<String, Set<String>> luni = new HashMap<>();
luni.put("A", new HashSet<String>(500));
luni.put("B", new HashSet<String>(500));
luni.put("C", new HashSet<String>(500));
// To add a value to B:
luni.get("B").add("some string");
```

or:

```
List<Set<String>> luni = new ArrayList<>(3);
luni.add(new HashSet<String>(500));
luni.add(new HashSet<String>(500));
luni.add(new HashSet<String>(500));
// To add a value to 'B' (index 1):
luni.get(1).add("some string");
```

I suggest using the first one. The second one uses index instead of A, B and C like you want.